# function doesn't execute on jquery document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that resize and centers images based on the surrounding container size (that in turn depend on the window size). I use jquery as js framework. The function need to be executed after document load (on document ready) but also when and if the user changes size of the browser, ie I have the following running in the html-document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   fixImageSizes();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   fixImageSizes();
});
```

But for some unknown reason the function is only executed when a user resizes the browser and not after loading. Can anyone please help with this?

(my function is below for knowledge...)

```
function fixImageSizes()
{
var cw = $('#imagecontainer').width();
var ch = $('#imagecontainer').height();
$('#imagecontainer img').each(function()
{
    var iw = $(this).css('width');
    var ih = $(this).css('height');
    if (parseInt(iw) < parseInt(cw)) // image width < viewport
    {
        var newih = Math.ceil(parseInt(ih) * parseInt(cw) / parseInt(iw)) + 'px';
        var newimargint = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(newih)/2) + 'px';
        var newimarginl = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(cw)/2) + 'px';
        $(this).css({'width':cw,'height':newih,'margin-left':newimarginl,'margin-top':newimargint});
    }
    if (parseInt(ih) < parseInt(ch)) // image height < viewport
    {
        var newiw = Math.ceil(parseInt(iw) * parseInt(ch) / parseInt(ih)) + 'px';
        var newimargint = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(ch)/2) + 'px';
        var newimarginl = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(newiw)/2) + 'px';
        $(this).css({'width':newiw,'height':ch,'margin-left':newimarginl,'margin-top':newimargint});
    }
    if (parseInt(ih) > parseInt(ch) && parseInt(iw) > parseInt(cw)) // viewport smaller than image, shrink image
    {
        if (parseInt(ch) - parseInt(ih) > parseInt(cw) - parseInt(iw)) // difference is less on height
        {
            var newiw = Math.ceil(parseInt(iw) * parseInt(ch) / parseInt(ih)) + 'px';
            var newimargint = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(ch)/2) + 'px';
            var newimarginl = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(newiw)/2) + 'px';
            $(this).css({'width':newiw,'height':ch,'margin-left':newimarginl,'margin-top':newimargint});
        } 
        else // difference less on width
        {
            var newih = Math.ceil(parseInt(ih) * parseInt(cw) / parseInt(iw)) + 'px';
            var newimargint = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(newih)/2) + 'px';
            var newimarginl = '-' + Math.ceil(parseInt(cw)/2) + 'px';
            $(this).css({'width':cw,'height':newih,'margin-left':newimarginl,'margin-top':newimargint});
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Why do you think the function was not executing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `load` event instead of the `ready` event.

The `ready` event runs after the document has loaded, but before the images has loaded, so you won't have the correct size of all elements.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure whether that is his problem. He does not get the sizes of the images, but only of their wrapper element - the single `<img>`s seem to have css width and height

Comment: @Bergi: Yes I get the image sizes with $('#imagecontainer img').each(function()

Comment: @jtheman: No, you get the css widths and heights of the images, not their actual sizes.

Comment: @jtheman: You don't have to use `parseInt` on the values that you get from the `width` and `height` methods as they are already numeric. Consider if you should use those methods to get the size of the images also, rather than getting their CSS settings.

Comment: @Guffa: Hmm. I tried using $(window).load(function() instead of document ready but the same result. As soon as I grab the browser window all images are resized correctly... But never before...

Comment: @jtheman: Do you set any CSS size on the images in the HTML code? Otherwise the function only works the second time you run it, and then on.

Comment: thanks! got it working now with all good tips from you! :) 1. removed css-sizing. 2. removed unnecessary parseint and cleared code a bit, 3. checking this.complete as described below!!! Great.

Answer (score 1):

The function is probably executing (you can double-check with a simple alert), but the images you are "fixing" is probably not loaded yet. You can use the `window.onload` event or listen to the image load event like this:

```
var scale = function() {
    // rescale
};

$('#imagecontainer img').each(function() {
    this.complete ? scale.call(this) : $(this).load(scale);
});
```

Comment: You should not use `arguments.callee`, which is not supported in strict mode. Just name the function.

Comment: You already got the upvote, I just thought a named function expression would be nicer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function (){
    fixImageSizes();
});
```